# Workflow for managing schema changes with Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, database-schema, doctrine-migrations

During development, I run Doctrine's `schema:update` command often to sync the database schema to my changing entity definitions. Once I'm ready to commit a feature, I want to roll up all the changes into a [migration class](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/latest/reference/introduction.html) which I can commit to git.

The problem is that in order to run `migrations:diff` I need to roll back the database schema to its state before I started messing with `schema:update`. Doing `schema:drop` then `migrations:migrate` is no good because dropping the schema doesn't drop the `migration_versions` table. That means I have to go into MySQL and manually drop all databases before running the existing migrations and creating the new one.

It works but it feels like I'm doing it wrong. Any better ideas?

Comment: I am trying to find out the same thing. Just wondering if you worked out a workflow for managing schema changes with Doctrine2?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know 100% correct answer to the question, but there was one option. Every time you need to run `schema:update --force` first dump sql with `schema:update --dump-sql` and store it. Then, the need to rollback base is not necessary

Comment: For anybody that happens to be looking at this, note that you can use `schema:update --force --dump-sql` to execute the update and give you the SQL in one go.